# I cannot access any web browser

Tags: snap

To be more specific, I think something is wrong with snap that it refuses to open firefox or chromium. I can still access the internet since I can play online games on Steam.

When I try to refresh snap via CC, I get two errors:
unsupported version 0 of Verdef record
unsupported version 0 of Verneed record

Ubuntu 22.04
snap 2.57.6

Other notes: Ive had this problem persist for a few days, whenever I use firefox for a while, any new tabs would just crash and if I close firefox and open a new one, it would just not open, no message or anything. Restarting the computer would fix this, but I rather not have to restart my computer every hour or so. I tried snap refresh, but all it says is "all snaps up to date" so im not sure its entirely a snap issue.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1445898/edit) to show complete input and output of `sudo snap refresh`. Do not edit or summarize.

Comment: Unless you insist on using Snap, you don't HAVE to use snap to install web browsers.

Comment: i figure trying that approach would be my next step, but im only guessing snap is the issue. I restarted my computer, and the broswer works fine, but eventually any new tabs would crash, and if i close the browser, I run into the same problem where I cant open up firefox or chromium. using sudo snap refresh just returns "all snaps up to date" this time.